# which antennas is better for 433 Mhz 30dbi LoRa module

Tags: antenna, 433mhz, lora, smith-chart

I am searching a antenna for LoRa module. my first priority is distance. which is more long range, it is better for me. There are 3, 433Mhz 3dBi antennas. Can you help me which is best and why? if you give a basic information about smith chart and swr chart, I will be appreciated to you.

[image]

I will use [this LoRa module](https://www.ebyte.com/en/product-view-news.aspx?id=108)

**First one [Link](https://www.ebyte.com/en/product-view-news.html?id=711) charts**

[image]

**Second one [Link](https://www.ebyte.com/en/product-view-news.html?id=793)**

[image]

**Last one [Link](https://www.ebyte.com/en/product-view-news.html?id=787)**

[image]

Comment: your question makes no sense: Antennas don't have a range, and your antenna smith chart tells us nothing about your system – neither impedance of your device (which quite likely isn't very close to what you need, anyway, so you'll need matching anyways, so the smith chart *really* doesn't matter much, if at all, just tells you what kind of matching circuit you'll need), nor about the actually important factors (directivity and your geometric setup). So, all in all, you're asking us "how to test an antenna for an unspecified use case", and that's, I'm afraid, really too broad.

Comment: (Full disclosure: I've voted to close this as "needs focus", because the Smith chart doesn't tell us which antenna is "better", and "reach" is a system, not an antenna property, which means you're lacking too many basics to be explained in a compact answer.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller well you are right I've very weak knowledge about antennas. While I was buying antenna, I ve seen those 3 antenna and I didnt match which is best for me. I will use this lora module https://www.ebyte.com/en/product-view-news.aspx?id=108 .

Comment: Which country are you intending to use those in? The only region where LoRa 433 is normalised is the EU region, and the limit there is 12.15 dBm EIRP (that means including antenna gain). Other regions will likely have different limits, if they allow use of the 433 MHz band at all for LoRa.

Comment: Also note that the label on the picture show an FCC ID which is only valid for the 915 MHz band. Unless the real device has a different FCC ID for operation in the 433 MHz band, it is illegal to operate in the US. It’s probably not approved in many/most other countries either.

Comment: @jcaron Where did you get 12.15dBm from? The limit of the 433 band in EU is generally 10dBm ERP. Some European contries have national rules overriding the EU-wide attempts of standardization.

Comment: @Lundin the first Google result I found :-) which happened to be the LoRaWAN 1.0.3 Regional Parameters https://lora-alliance.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/lorawan_regional_parameters_v1.0.3reva_0.pdf#page32 I have to admit I didn’t check further.

Comment: @jcaron Okay, that document seems to be wrong. [Decision 2006/771/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:02006D0771(01)-20190813&from=EN) is which is what applies unless there's national rules listed. For non-specific SRD on the band 433,05-434,79, you have to keep 10mW ERP if you fulfil the 10% duty cycle requirement, otherwise 1mW ERP. Also that same LoRA document confuses the radio standard EN/ETSI 300 220 with the band allocation requirements, which is also wrong.

Comment: The ETSI spec says 10 mW (i.e. 10 dBm) **ERP**. EIRP = ERP + 2.15 dBm.

Comment: @jcaron Ah yeah that could be it... but EIRP is a weird metric and not how the test houses do it iirc. They'll measure field strength at some fixed length at some places all around your device and if it's larger than specified, you fail the test. "But I was only sending in direction x" is a very strange rationale for going beyond the band limits.

Comment: And I just checked the actual standard 300 220 and it doesn't mention any loop hole for antenna gain either, as far as I can see. The definition or ERP from the standard: "For equipment with a permanent or temporary antenna connection it may be taken as the power delivered from that connector taking into account the antenna gain." So no, you get no special treatment just because you have antenna gain, quite the contrary.

Comment: @jcaron so you say selling this device (30db) is illegal in Turkey? but it is selling on internet Are there any misunderstanding https://www.direnc.net/lora-sx1276-868mhz-transceiver-modulu

Comment: @mehmet I don’t know the rules in Turkey, you would have to look them up. Limits there may be different, and even if they’re not, depending on the local rules, you may be allowed to import/buy/sell it provided you don’t exceed the allowed limits. But in many countries you can’t import, buy, sell or operate radio equipment that hasn’t been tested/certified to be within the local rules.

Answer (score 1):

A dummy load has a perfect match across a wide spectrum. That doesn't make them a good antenna.

What you want are radiation patterns and antenna efficiency.
As a rule of thumb; the smaller you try and make an antenna for a given wavelength, the lower the efficiency of the antenna.

Comment: I was just about to make that comment.

Comment: so what do you think of this LoRa module, if you were in my place, which antenna would you choose?

Comment: If I were in your place, I'd have way more information that has been asked for in the comments already, based on which I could actually make a decision. As said in the other comments, from your Smith charts alone, no decision can be made, and you will have to acquire more expertise yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Well after watching some videos and reading I think first one is better (intheory) because it is closest to 50 ohm (smith chart) and lowest swr

Viode links:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pjcEKQY_Tk

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6cVYsHCLKq8

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3PBL9oLPX8

docs:

https://www.ebyte.com/en/new-view-info.html?id=304

https://www.coredump.ch/2017/04/30/lorawan-868mhz-antenna-test-part-2/